# Using SciKit's kMeans to Cluster One's Own Documents

Tags: scikit-learn

The SciKit site offers [this k-means demo](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/auto_examples/document_clustering.html#example-document-clustering-py), and I'd like to use as much of it as possible to cluster some of my own documents, since I'm new to both machine learning and SciKit.  The problem is getting my documents in a form that fits their demonstration.

Here is the "problem area" from SciKit's example:

```
dataset = fetch_20newsgroups(subset='all', categories=categories, shuffle=True, random_state=42)
labels = dataset.target
true_k = np.unique(labels).shape[0]
```

As can be seen, in the example, the authors use/"fetch" a data set named "20newsgroups," the call for which (according to [this page](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/datasets/index.html); see the second paragraph of 7.7) "returns a list of the raw text files that can be fed to text feature extractors."  I am not relying on a list of "text files" -- as can be seen in my code below -- but I can place my "documents" in whatever form is necessary.

How can I use the SciKit example without having to place my "documents" in text files?  Or is it standard practice only to cluster documents from text files rather than the database on which the documents live?  It's simply not clear from the demo/documentation what in the example is completely superfluous, used because it made the authors' lives easier, and what isn't.  Or at least it's not clear to me.

```
if cursor.rowcount > 0: #don't bother doing anything if we don't get anything from the database
data = cursor.fetchall()    
for row in data:
    temp_string = row[0]+" "+row[1]+" "+row[3]+" "+row[4] # currently skipping the event_url: row[2]
    page        = BeautifulSoup((''.join(temp_string)))  
    pagetwo     = str(page)
    clean_text  = nltk.clean_html(pagetwo)
    tokens      = nltk.word_tokenize(clean_text)
    fin_doc     = "" + "\n"
    for word in tokens:
        fin_word = stemmer.stem(word).lower()
        if fin_word not in stopwords and len(fin_word) > 2:
            fin_doc += fin_word + " "
    
    documents.append(fin_doc)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documents are just a list of strings, one string for each document, iirc.
The documentation is a bit unclear on this one. `fetch_20newsgroups` downloads the dataset as files, but the representation in the code is the content of the files, not the files themselves.